# php variable printing extra numbers

Tags: javascript, php, html

I working on a small form using PHP, the user enter a code a code and if the code is not found the form need to go back, I am trying to do that using this code but it not working

the `$code` contains the id of the page which is `208`, but for some reason is not only printing `208` it is printing `%20208` any ideas why is doing this.

```
<?php
die('<center>code dont exist<br>Try again!</center>   
             <script type="text/javascript">
               function backToMain() { 
               window.location = "codes.php?id= '.$code. '"; 
            }
               setTimeout("backToMain()", 3000);
             </script>');
```

Comment: %20 is a space thats why it has that

Comment: yep it is the white space from  window.location = "codes.php?id=HERE'.$code. '";

Comment: You should always clean user input before using it. There's no way to guarantee that any form data being received is correct, unless you check it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put a space between `id=` and the beginning of the `$code`. The `%20` is a space, once the URL is correctly encoded. Remove it:

```
<?php
die('<center>code dont exist<br>Try again!</center>   
         <script type="text/javascript">
           function backToMain() { 
           window.location = "codes.php?id='.$code.'"; 
        }
           setTimeout("backToMain()", 3000);
         </script>');
```

If your `$code` can contains space, you should also apply the [`trim()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on it.

Answer (score 3):

[trim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will remove all spaces. also remove space after `id=`.

try this:

```
<?php
die('<center>code dont exist<br>Try again!</center>   
             <script type="text/javascript">
               function backToMain() { 
               window.location = "codes.php?id='.trim($code). '"; 
            }
               setTimeout("backToMain()", 3000);
             </script>');
```